How do I create an array out of specific parts of JSON data?
After calling an API, I have some data in JSON format. Within that format, there is an array with sub-parts (I apologize, I don't know the terminology) that exist inside each key of the array.
{
  "id": "<my id>",
  "bots": [],
  "avatar": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1c1c09ef-3937-4408-8f31-04ec6bec2238-profile_image-300x300.png",
  "channelEmotes": [],
  "sharedEmotes": [
    {
      "id": "<emote id>",
      "code": "<emote name>",
      "imageType": "<filetype>",
      "animated": true,
      "user": {
        "id": "<emote creator id>",
        "name": "<emote creator username>",
        "displayName": "<emote creator display name>",
        "providerId": "<not sure what this field is actually>"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "<emote id>",
      "code": "<emote name>",
      "imageType": "<filetype>",
      "animated": true,
      "user": {
        "id": "<emote creator id>",
        "name": "<emote creator username>",
        "displayName": "<emote creator display name>",
        "providerId": "<not sure what this field is actually>"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Specifically, I want to make separate arrays for all the emote name, emote id, and filetypes like (I plan to have many more than these two)
var emotecodes = [code0, code1, ...];
var emoteids = [id0, id1, ...];
var emotefiletypes = [imageType0, imageType1, ...];

I've tried various other things I've found around the internet but have had no success.

I've tried various other things other than what? You haven't done anything!

You can use the reduce function on the sharedEmotes property of the json


const jsonData = {
  "id": "<my id>",
  "bots": [],
  "avatar": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1c1c09ef-3937-4408-8f31-04ec6bec2238-profile_image-300x300.png",
  "channelEmotes": [],
  "sharedEmotes": [{
      "id": "<emote id>",
      "code": "<emote name>",
      "imageType": "<filetype>",
      "animated": true,
      "user": {
        "id": "<emote creator id>",
        "name": "<emote creator username>",
        "displayName": "<emote creator display name>",
        "providerId": "<not sure what this field is actually>"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "<emote id>",
      "code": "<emote name>",
      "imageType": "<filetype>",
      "animated": true,
      "user": {
        "id": "<emote creator id>",
        "name": "<emote creator username>",
        "displayName": "<emote creator display name>",
        "providerId": "<not sure what this field is actually>"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const formattedData = jsonData.sharedEmotes.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  acc.emotecodes.push(curr.code);
  acc.emoteids.push(curr.id);
  acc.emotefiletypes.push(curr.imageType);


  return acc;
}, {
  emotecodes: [],
  emoteids: [],
  emotefiletypes: []
});


console.log(formattedData.emotecodes, formattedData.emoteids, formattedData.emotefiletypes)




To create separate arrays for the emote names, emote ids, and filetypes from the JSON data, you can use the map function in JavaScript. The map function will allow you to extract specific parts of the JSON data and create new arrays based on those parts.
const emotecodes = data.sharedEmotes.map(emote => emote.code);
const emoteids = data.sharedEmotes.map(emote => emote.id);
const emotefiletypes = data.sharedEmotes.map(emote => emote.imageType)


You need to explain your code for the OP to understand. See How to Answer

@thecodingsage - to be fair, OP posted NO code, I think the answer fits the level of effort in the question :p

Array.prototype.map() method would do the work. Also consider using const or let to declare variables instead of var (Here is why).


const apiJSONData = {
    id: '<my id>',
    bots: [],
    avatar:
      'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1c1c09ef-3937-4408-8f31-04ec6bec2238-profile_image-300x300.png',
    channelEmotes: [],
    sharedEmotes: [
      {
        id: '<emote id>',
        code: '<emote name>',
        imageType: '<filetype>',
        animated: true,
        user: {
          id: '<emote creator id>',
          name: '<emote creator username>',
          displayName: '<emote creator display name>',
          providerId: '<not sure what this field is actually>',
        },
      },
      {
        id: '<emote id>',
        code: '<emote name>',
        imageType: '<filetype>',
        animated: true,
        user: {
          id: '<emote creator id>',
          name: '<emote creator username>',
          displayName: '<emote creator display name>',
          providerId: '<not sure what this field is actually>',
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  const emoteCodes = apiJSONData.sharedEmotes.map((emoteObj) => emoteObj.code);
  const emoteIds = apiJSONData.sharedEmotes.map((emoteObj) => emoteObj.id);
  const emoteFileTypes = apiJSONData.sharedEmotes.map(
    (emoteObj) => emoteObj.imageType
  );

  console.log(emoteCodes);
  console.log(emoteIds);
  console.log(emoteFileTypes);




This will work, but this solution is iterating the array thrice for the same job which can be done in one iteration. Alternatively, you can also use plain for..loop

You are right; a traditional for...loop can indeed be more performant for data-heavy iterations since it avoids multiple passes over the array. However, modern array methods (forEach, map, filter, etc.) offer more readable and expressive code, which clearly conveys the intent and is easier to maintain. For many use cases, the readability and clarity provided by these methods outweigh the slight performance difference, but it's always good to consider the specific context.
